# xcodeがタブ移動で100%クラッシュする

Tags: xcode

xcodeでタブを１個だけ開いている状態で、タブを掴んで移動して離すと、１００％の確立でクラッシュします。
自分だけでしょうか？

対策あればお願いします。
（また、自分だけに起こっているのか知りたいです）

バージョンは　Version 7.3 (7D175)

Comment: 私の環境でも同じ操作で必ずクラッシュすることを確認しました。Version 7.3 (7D175)

Comment: まじですか…
ってことはおそらく皆の環境ですね
それがわかっただけですっきりしました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

対策というか、対応ありました。
と言うのは、自分結構何度も何度も間違ってタブを掴んでしまうことがありまして、
しょっちゅうクラッシュしていました。

タブを間違って掴んでしまったらそのまま画面上部の端に押し付けると
横にビヨーンんて広がるのでその時はなせばクラッシュを回避できます。